# Mocking Rest API with Swagger / OpenAPI Documentation

Tags: spring, rest, mocking, swagger, openapi

Whole idea is to create Mock service for UI team to test without actual API.

- We have defined specification in .yaml files.
- Now want to generate Swagger-UI and Mock rest URI with mock data.
- Using spring-boot.

Please suggest some way to generate the same.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you've the API documented in Swagger/OpenAPI spec (YAML format), you can use [Swagger Codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) to generate Spring boot server stub.

Please pull the latest master of https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen and follow the instruction in the wiki:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/wiki/Server-stub-generator-HOWTO#java-springboot

Answer (score 0):

Generating code for stub server is not a great option. Instead you may want to look at the several API mocking tools that let you create a mock server based on your Swagger / OpenAPI specification.

Here is a relevant [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38344711/444252) and also suggest looking this list of [API mock servers](https://openapi.tools/#mock).