# Swagger/OpenAPI mock server

Tags: mocking, swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi

I have an API reference in a Swagger file. I want to create a very simple mock server, so that when I call e.g.:

`mymockurl.com/users` it will return a predefined JSON (no need to connect to a database).

What's the easiest way to do this? I'm not a backend guy.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

[**SwaggerHub**](https://swagger.io/tools/swaggerhub/) provides a [mock server](https://support.smartbear.com/swaggerhub/docs/integrations/api-auto-mocking.html) for OpenAPI 2.0 and 3.0 specs. Mocking is supported on both free and paid plans.

To use the mock server, import your spec into SwaggerHub and enable "API Auto Mocking". Mock responses can be JSON, YAML and XML, and are generated based on your response schemas and the `example`, `default` and `enum` values defined in the schemas.

***Disclosure**: I work for the company that makes SwaggerHub.*

Comment: Great! It does exactly what I needed! I'm marking this as an answer. The one thing I don't like is the pricing - there should be a smaller plan for freelancers who just want to have couple of private APIs.

Comment: Can I deploy such such server locally on my network? Or it can be done only using swaggerhub.com?

Comment: @IvanVinogradov SwaggerHub has both SaaS and On-Premise versions, and other answers mention mock tools that you can install and use locally.

Comment: @Helen is SwaggerHub opensource?

Comment: @MaxBarrass No.

Comment: @Helen - I've defined multiple response examples but my virt server endpoint provided by the "API Auto Mocking" only ever returns the first example in the list.  Is there a way to get it to randomly chose a different one each time?

Comment: @John currently this is [not supported](https://support.smartbear.com/swaggerhub/docs/integrations/api-auto-mocking.html#how): _"if `examples` contain multiple examples, the first example will be used"_. Please feel free to [submit a feature request](https://support.smartbear.com/swaggerhub/message/). (However, [randomized responses](https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/virtualization/configure/dispatch/index.html) are supported in our [ReadyAPI Virtualization](https://smartbear.com/product/ready-api/features/api-virtualization-features/) product if that's an option for you.)

Answer (score 88):

An easy way to create simple mock from an OpenAPI (fka Swagger) spec without code is to use a tool call [prism](http://stoplight.io/platform/prism) available at http://github.com/stoplightio/prism written in Typescript.

This command line is all you need:

```
./prism run --mock --list --spec <your swagger spec file>
```

The mock server will return a dynamic response based on the OpenAPI spec.
If examples are provided in the spec, prism will return them, if not it will generate dummy data based on the spec.

**Edit (Aug 2020):**

The command has changed in the latest version. The following will do:

```
prism mock <your spec file>
```

It accepts swagger and postman doc as well.

Comment: The page has moved to http://stoplight.io/platform/prism/ - Also see https://github.com/stoplightio/prism

Comment: Thanks for clarifying "Open API (fka. Swagger)"! I'm a little late to this game.

Comment: Looks like this option "run" is outdated and no longer available in the newest version of prism. Apparently it has been replaced by "mock", but I have not found any replacement for "--list"

Comment: Just a short heads up: prism is not open source software and the license of prism itself is unclear. The MIT licensed installers are downloading a binary package of prism.

Comment: The team added the Apache 2.0 license at the end of May 2019. As a result, the software license is no longer unclear.

Comment: The [prism](http://stoplight.io/platform/prism) link is invalid, **404 This page doesn't exist!**

Comment: It does not seem to support different responses based on conditions

Answer (score 26):

[Imposter](https://github.com/outofcoffee/imposter) is a **a scriptable, multipurpose mock server** written in Java.

Very easy to setup in a **Docker** environment and provides a *Swagger UI* to play with your mock api.

Let's see an example setup

1. Have a swagger configuration ready in a file in the folder `config/petstore.yaml`

   ```
    swagger: "2.0"
    info:
    version: 1.0.0
    title: Swagger Petstore
        .
        .
        .
   ```

You can copy the example swagger specification from [here](https://github.com/outofcoffee/imposter/blob/master/plugin/openapi/src/test/resources/config/petstore-expanded.yaml).

2. Create a configuration file for *Imposter* in `config/openapi-plugin-petstore-config.json`

   ```
    {
      "plugin": "com.gatehill.imposter.plugin.openapi.OpenApiPluginImpl",
      "specFile": "petstore.yaml"
    }
   ```

   Name of the configuration file has to end with `-config.json`.
3. Run ***Imposter*** with *Docker*

   Ensure that your shell is placed in the parent directory of `config` and run

   ```
    docker run -ti -p 8443:8443 \
    -v $(pwd)/config:/opt/imposter/config \
    outofcoffee/imposter-openapi
   ```
4. Open http://localhost:8443/_spec/ to play with your Mock Server and Swagger UI

   [image: Imposter Mock API]

Comment: Disclosure: I'm the author of the above project, Imposter. Since the original poster asked about 'the easiest way to do this', I'd also like to point you to the free hosted version of Imposter, over on https://www.remotebot.io/mocks - the hosted version doesn't require you to run anything yourself, just upload your Swagger API spec and it will create an instant mock.

Comment: @outofcoffee I like imposter and find it easy to setup on my mac.  just wondering , is it possible to use imposter without docker specially in windows machines.

Comment: Hi @Akash, yes - see the 'Running as a standalone Java application' section in the docs: https://github.com/outofcoffee/imposter/blob/master/docs/getting_started.md#running-as-a-standalone-java-application

Comment: @outofcoffee, does it offer a mechanism to dynamically get different responses based on http return codes e.g: `200`, `404` for the same API call?

Comment: Hi @kaizenCoder, yes - you can control the response behaviour via scripting.

This enables you to choose which status code (and thus corresponding example response) to return. You can examine various properties of the request (headers, parameters etc.) to determine if you want to return an error code or a success status code. The example in the spec for the status code you specify will be returned.

Here's some information about scripting responses: https://github.com/outofcoffee/imposter/blob/master/docs/scripting.md

Comment: [remotebot.io/mocks](https://www.remotebot.io/mocks) not working anymore.

Comment: Looks like he moved it to https://www.mocks.cloud/

Answer (score 16):

Given the OpenAPI/Swagger spec, you can use [Swagger Codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) to generate server stub in different server frameworks (e.g. Java Spring. PHP Slim, Ruby on Rails5, etc).

Here is the related documentation:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/wiki/Server-stub-generator-HOWTO

UPDATE: In May 2018, about 50 top contributors of Swagger Codegen decided to fork the project to create a community-driven version called [OpenAPI Generator](https://openapi-generator.tech). Please refer to the [Q&A](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/qna.md) for the reasons behind the fork.

Comment: Will this return predefined json responses? Can you help @wing328?

Comment: It may depend on the generator. Please start the discussion in https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues instead.

Comment: I opened an issue few daya ago but no response yet: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/5310 I tried using inflector as well but no luck there. How do I get predefined json responses to be returned using swagger? The UI developer would want to try out the API and see the sample response.

Answer (score 6):

The Mock-Server project supports creating stubs based on Swagger/OpenAPI Specs.

https://www.mock-server.com/mock_server/using_openapi.html

Answer (score 5):

Here is the [docker container](https://github.com/mrVanDalo/swagger-api-mock-docker) for mock api server from swagger yaml.

```
docker run -i \
    -p 8000:8000 \
    -v /path/to/file.yaml:/data/swagger.yaml \
    -t palo/swagger-api-mock:latest
```

This is internally using [swagger-mock-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-mock-api)

Answer (score 3):

I docker composed Swagger Editor, Swagger UI and Swagger mock api server to handle them more easily. Check it out.
There is a sample swagger spec in this so the Editor, UI and the mock API server will run without any configuration from the start. All you need to do is edit the swagger spec, save swagger.json and swagger.yaml, and restart docker.

[swagger-all-in-one-docker-compose](https://github.com/elevennines-inc/swagger-all-in-one-docker-compose)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 2):

I created mock api server myself that can server `swagger.json` file. It is very easy to setup locally if you have python installed.

Have a look at this: https://github.com/bikcrum/Mock-API-server

Just use this command to serve your `swagger.json` file which will create API endpoints based on specification on the swagger file.

#### Quick and straightforward

```
python app.py -s /path/to/swagger.json
```

#### Extended options

```
usage: app.py [-h] -s SOURCE [-p PORT] [-t {swagger}] [-sc STATUS_CODE] [-r RANDOM_SEED] [-d DEFAULT_VALUE [DEFAULT_VALUE ...]]
              [-l LIST_SIZE [LIST_SIZE ...]]

Options for mock responses

Required and optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit

  -s SOURCE, --source SOURCE
                        (Required) API reference source file path.
  
  -p PORT, --port PORT  (Optional,default=5000) Port number the app runs on.

  -t {swagger}, --type {swagger}
                        (Optional,default='swagger') Type of API reference. Currently only supports Swagger.

  -sc STATUS_CODE, --status_code STATUS_CODE
                        (Optional,default=200) Generates responses with status code provided.

  -r RANDOM_SEED, --random_seed RANDOM_SEED
                        (Optional) Generates random responses based on seed value.

  -d DEFAULT_VALUE [DEFAULT_VALUE ...], --default_value DEFAULT_VALUE [DEFAULT_VALUE ...]
                        (Optional) Sets default values in response body. Format key=value.

  -l LIST_SIZE [LIST_SIZE ...], --list_size LIST_SIZE [LIST_SIZE ...]
                        (Optional,default=[2]) Sets default size of list in response body.
```

Answer (score 2):

Recently I have come across Microcks.io and it has helped me solve number of problems.
Also found Apicur.io for editing/creating swagger files. A standard worth embrasing.

Answer (score 2):

[**Specmatic**](https://specmatic.in/) lets you create a mock server with your OpenAPI Specifications (Please see [video demo](https://youtu.be/U5Agz-mvYIU?t=749)). Here is the "[getting started](https://specmatic.in/getting_started.html#consumer-side---contract-as-a-stub--smart-mock)" guide.

An important aspect to consider while creating mock servers is that the canned responses / expectations / stub data that you setup should never go out of sync with your OpenAPI Specifications (Stale Stubs). This is guaranteed with Specmatic [Smart Mocks](https://specmatic.in/#contract-as-stub).

Disclosure: I am lead developer and CTO at Specmatic

Answer (score 2):

Use [Mockoon](https://mockoon.com/), "Mockoon is the easiest and quickest way to design and run mock REST APIs. No remote deployment, no account required, free and open-source." It has the best user-friendly GUI in my opinion. It also has a CLI and Serverless function option. You can generate mock endpoints from your Swagger/Open API files and export them after you've made changes.

There are many other features: Multiple responses per route, File serving, etc. See https://mockoon.com/features/ for details.

You can see Mockoon's comparison to other products here: https://mockoon.com/compare/

Answer (score 1):

MockLab now supports auto-generation of mock APIs from an imported Swagger definition. And you can also set it up as a webhook received in Swaggerhub so it gets updated on every save/publish:

[https://www.mocklab.io/blog/mocklab-now-supports-swagger-and-swaggerhub/](https://www.mocklab.io/blog/mocklab-now-supports-swagger-and-swaggerhub/?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=answer&utm_campaign=swagger-mock-server)

Answer (score 0):

[openapi-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openapi-mock) is a CLI wrapper for [swagger-node-runner](https://github.com/theganyo/swagger-node-runner) and [sway](https://github.com/apigee-127/sway) specifically to start a mock server from an openapi/swagger spec file.

Comment: If it only worked to return example data from Swagger definition by the mock it server, or it's just me who doesn't know how to configure it...