# how to generate dummy response from swagger

Tags: rest, api, swagger, swagger-editor

As you might know, Swagger itself provides to test the API using 'Try it out' option as in http://petstore.swagger.io/#!/pet/findPetsByStatus.

I do not know how swagger manages this 'try it out' option but I want to manually keep the response as per different request. Does swagger simulate response without having a proper server ?

Is it possible with swagger? If yes, how ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ron,  can you please look at this ?

Comment: @dilip-krishnan , can you help me ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swagger mock server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38344711/swagger-mock-server)

Answer (score 2):

Swagger's "try it out" function works by actually calling a live API.  You can't use it without a real API running.  So it is not possible to simulate responses with the Swagger documentation as it is written.