# Problem with editing OpenApi 3.0 with Swagger

Tags: swagger

I am new to Swagger and today created first project (OpenApi 3), but when I try to open it editor is disabled and I am getting message:

> "Note: "Try it out" is disabled because no servers are specified in
>   the "servers" array. Please see: info on OAS3 servers"

I understand that I should change something in configuraton with servers array, but how and where to do so, when editor is disabled?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the significance of servers property in OpenAPI 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50546573/what-is-the-significance-of-servers-property-in-openapi-3-0)

Comment: See also https://swagger.io/docs/specification/api-host-and-base-path/. And if you need a mock server, see [OpenAPI 3.0 mock generator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44107798/113116).

Comment: Nope it doesn't resolving my problem.

Comment: Please post your YAML file so that others can reproduce your issue. Also, what editor do you use - http://editor.swagger.io or SwaggerHub or something else?

Comment: I work with default online editor on Swagger website how can I get yaml file?

Comment: Here is link to screenshot: http://piotrwozniak.pl/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/sw.png

Comment: Having the same issue. I do have servers in YAML def, but still getting this warning