# Undestanding the flow of swagger UI

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to mock the REST API using swagger.. I currently created nodejs project in which the default js appreas which is hello_world.js in ./api/controllers/hello_world.js.

Now I want to create a new controller and want to refer that to my YAML, that is from swaggerUI.. How can I do it? Any link would be much useful.

I am only mocking APIS, not developing.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you're interested in mocking only, check out this Q&A: [Swagger mock server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38344711/113116).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the swagger codegen project, which generates server stubs based on the api specification. Node.js is among the supported languages: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen