# Dynamically controlled swagger / openapi mock server for testing purposes

Tags: testing, mocking, automated-tests, swagger, openapi

I'm looking for a project/tool that is able to get swagger / openapi specifications file as a parameter and generate a mock server that can be controlled programmatically via a REST API interface.

For example - if my API contains the following endpoint: "POST /v1/create"
and I have a swagger specs that describe that API, I would like my mock server to be executed in a way similar to:

```
mock-server -f swagger.yaml -p 8080
```

While the server runs, It will be possible to interact with it's own REST API (on some control interface via a different port) and change the behavior of the running swagger mock server - i.e: change response code, set response content etc'

I would like to use such mock-server as part of my system-tests suite to better verify my service behavior when interacting with other services - without the need to run those 'real' services.

I'm looking for something similar in spirit to Shopyify's ToxiProxy (https://github.com/Shopify/toxiproxy) but with the above capabilities.

Thanks!

Eldad

Comment: Do any of [these mock servers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38344711/113116) suit your needs?

Comment: No, SwaggerHub and Prism are close but it seems they only allow to set static responses which is nice but not good for automated testing in which I would like to have the ability to change the API response as part of my test setup/teardown steps.

Comment: @Eldad : have you found a solution ? Do you accept the answer?

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm a bit late to the party on this one, but for future searchers, MockLab now supports auto-generation of mock APIs from an imported Swagger definition and Swaggerhub webhooks.

More details here:
https://www.mocklab.io/blog/mocklab-now-supports-swagger-and-swaggerhub/

Answer (score 1):

I believe [Specmatic](https://specmatic.in/) should help you with this.

> mock-server -f swagger.yaml -p 8080

Specmatic works exactly this way. To start a mock server with an OpenAPI specification file we can run below command.

```
specmatic stub service.yaml --port 8080
```

Here is the [documentation](https://specmatic.in/getting_started.html#consumer-side---contract-as-a-stub--smart-mock).

> While the server runs, It will be possible to interact with it's own REST API (on some control interface via a different port) and change the behaviour of the running swagger mock server - i.e: change response code, set response content etc'

This is also supported. Specmatic has a http interface to which you can post the request and response mappings / expectations. We call this dynamic mocks. Here is the [documentation](https://specmatic.in/documentation/service_virtualization_tutorial.html#dynamic-mocking---setting-expecations-over-specmatic-http-api).

Here is a [video](https://youtu.be/U5Agz-mvYIU?t=748) on this.

Disclosure: I am lead dev and CTO at Specmatic