# Change swagger mock default response

Tags: swagger, swagger-node-express

I'm currently using Swagger node.js and I am able to get a response through swagger with the mock option enabled (`swagger project start -m`)

However, when I hit the API, the mock response is very primitive.

```
            "description": "Sample text",
            "disabled": true,
```

So for string properties, I get back "Sample Text" and for Boolean, I get back True.
Is there any way to control these values? Maybe force swagger to refer to the example property?

I looked online, but couldn't find any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

`swagger-node-express` does not use the `example` values specified in the API definition. To customize mock responses, you'll need to create custom mock controllers.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node/blob/master/docs/mock-mode.md#implementing-mock-mode-controllers):

> By default, mock mode returns programmed responses, like "Sample text" for a string, a number for an integer, and so on.
>
> But you can also create mock controllers with handler methods that return custom responses.
>
> Place these custom "mock" controllers in the `/api/mock` directory.

But there are other [OpenAPI/Swagger mock servers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38344711/113116) that support `example` values.