# Create a mock server from OpenAPI spec

Tags: go, openapi, openapi-generator

I am trying to develop a Go application that makes request to an HTTP server and process the response.

I would like to mock this server when running `go test ./...`.

My endpoint of interest accepts `POST` request to `/` with 2 parameters, something like:

```yaml
---
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: User API
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  /:
    post:
      summary: Get data
      requestBody:
        description: Get data
        required: true
        content:
          application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                optType:
                  type: string
                pwd:
                  type: string
              required:
                - optType
                - pwd
      responses:
        '201':
          description: User created successfully
          content:
            application/json:
              example:
                Data:
                  - 2304
                Information:
                  - 3.0
                  - 4
```

Ideally when running the unit test a web server should be spun up and will respond to the endpoint with a JSON like:

```json
{
    "Data": [
         2304
     ],
     "Information": [
         3.0
         4
     ]
}
```

At the moment I am using:

```golang
    server := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if r.Method != "POST" {
            t.Errorf("Expected ‘POST’ request, got ‘%s’", r.Method)
        }

        if path := r.URL.EscapedPath(); path != "/" {
            t.Errorf("Expected request to ‘/’, got ‘%s’", path)
        }

        err := r.ParseForm()
        if err != nil {
            t.Errorf("Error in ParseForm, got `%s`", err)
        }

        if optType := r.Form.Get("optType"); optType != "ReadRealTimeData" {
            t.Errorf("Expected `optType` with `ReadRealTimeData`, got ‘%s’", optType)
        }

        if pwd := r.Form.Get("pwd"); pwd != password {
            t.Errorf("Wrong `pwd`, got ‘%s’", pwd)
        }

        response_json := `{
            "Data": [2304],
            "Information": [
                3.0,
                4
            ]
        }`

        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        w.Write([]byte(response_json))
    }))
    defer server.Close()
```

Being able to simply use the OpenAPI YAML file would be much easier and more portable.

Any suggestion?

Comment: you can try this generator https://github.com/getkin/kin-openapi

Comment: Check out the tools listed in [Swagger/OpenAPI mock server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38344711/113116) and https://openapi.tools/#mock

Comment: Thanks for you reply.
I have had a look at kin-openapi but I cannot understand how to start the server, seems that I can only validate if a request is compatible, but it does not respond.
Am I correct?